# Correct way to get a nice gtk theme

Tags: themes, gtk, xmonad

I just tried xmonad and I'd like to know what is the correct way to avoid the ugly base gtk theme that shows up after a fresh install. I ran into lxappearance but some people were not satisfied it seems. So I thought I'd take some input on the best way to achieve what I want before jumping into it.

My target result is the nice and pretty ubuntu default theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered that the culprit is, in fact, `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session` or equivalent file.

Create or edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session` to be:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Xmonad/GNOME
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=xmonad
DesktopName=Unity
```

The important line is the last one. `DesktopName` **must** have the value `Unity`, even if you do not use it.

Also, create or edit `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-xmonad.desktop` to the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME with Xmonad
Comment=A GNOME fallback mode session using xmonad as the window manager.
Exec=gnome-session --session=xmonad
TryExec=gnome-session
Icon=
Type=Application
```

At login, choose **GNOME with Xmonad** from the session dropdown.

Everything, including themes, the desktop background and other minor things should work as expected.

Edit: if this does not seem to work, run gnome-session-properties (Startup Applications) and add `gnome-settings-daemon` to the list. (It's unlikely that this will work but it's worth a try.)

---

## **Update**

For newer versions of Ubuntu, try the following for `/usr/share/ghome-session/sessions/xmonad.session`:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Xmonad/GNOME
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;gnome-panel;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=xmonad
DefaultProvider-panel=unity-2d-panel
```

If the first doesn't work, I'm not sure this one will, either, but I'd try it anyway.